# How can I generate random variates from a from a PDF that I have defined?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

My problem is that `Pick` evaluates all the elements of a list at once. In my code I need a similar function that evaluates each element of a list. 
I need to generate 1000000 numbers for a PDF.

My code is:

```
n = 1000000;
yteste = RandomReal[{0, 2/3}, 2 n]; 
xteste = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2 n];

f[x_] := 2/3 (1 - Abs[x]^3)

If[Length[xaceitos] <= n, 
  AppendTo[xaceitos, Pick[xteste, UnitStep[f[xteste] - yteste], 1]], 
  Nothing]
```

Is there any other function that can do it?

Comment: Can you explain what you want your code to produce? What is the expected form of `xaceitos`, for instance?

Comment: I need to generate n numbers that follow the PDF f[x], this is the monte carlo Method. The problem is, when i use the rejection method i only receive less than n numbers. I need to receive exactly n numbers.

Comment: That is slightly clearer, but only a little. So, you want to sample under the curve of `f[x]` for `Abs[x] < 1`? If so: `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]; xaceitos = RandomVariate[dist, n]; Show[Histogram[xaceitos, Automatic, "PDF"], Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]]`

Comment: Yes, exactly. The curve of the histogram[xaceitos] must have the same shape o f[x].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @JM says, just use [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -1, 1}];

random = RandomVariate[dist, 10^6];
Length[random]
```

> 1000000

Visualization:

```
Histogram[random, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

[image]